# infinite message delivery loop with activeMQ and Broker Camel Component

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using activeMQ 5.9.

I'm trying to implement an interception type route in my activemq.xml, where I check if a particular header equals some value then send it to a different queue, otherwise allow it to continue.

I'm following the info here: http://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.html

My camel.xml file looks like this:

```
<camelContext id="camel" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="routeAboveQueueLimitTest">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:do.something"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.scope} == 'test'</simple>
                <to uri="activemq:queue:test.do.something"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <to uri="activemq:queue:do.something"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Then when I put a message on "activemq:queue:do.something" with header called scope = "test" it correctly routes to the "activemq:queue:test.do.something" queue.  However, when it doesn't have that header, it puts it back on the "activemq:queue:do.something" queue and processes it again and again and again!

That kind of seems logical, but the above page clearly says that you have to explicitly send it back to the broker component, and the 2nd example on the page shows exactly that.

I realise this could be worked around by sending it to a different queue if it doesn't have the header but that is undesirable at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intercept pattern would be much better suited for what you are looking.

```
    <intercept>
        <when><simple>${header.scope} == 'test'</simple></when>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:test.do.something"/>
    </intercept>
```

More info here: http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

This will allow messages without the scope header set to 'test' to continue, but will redirect messages that do have the test header.

Comment: agreed! But I need to route each queue to different test queues.  What I've since done is to dynamically setup an InterceptSendToEndpoint and add it to the camelContext.  It works great!

Answer (score 0):

InterceptSendToEndpoint is a better option here...

```
<interceptSendToEndpoint uri="activemq:queue:do.something">
    <when><simple>${header.scope} == 'test'</simple></when>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:test.do.something"/>
    <stop/>
</interceptSendToEndpoint>
```